# The constructor function in a pure virtual class should be "protected" or "public"?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, constructor, pure-virtual

The following example is from the book *"Inside C++ object model"*

```
class Abstract_base {
public:
    virtual ~Abstract_base () = 0;
    virtual void interface () const = 0;
    virtual const char* mumble () const 
    {
        return _mumble;
    }
protected:
    char *_mumble;
};
```

The author says if I want to initialize `_mumble`, the data member of the pure virtual base class, a **"protected constructor"** should be implemented.

But why **protected**? And why **"public constructor"** is not suitable for this class?

Thanks for your answers, and it would be perfect if there's an example.

Comment: Its pure-virtual. The only valid construction of such a thing is via derivation. Said derivation has access to a protected constructor. Nothing else (friends not withstanding) does. It doesn't matter in this case, but at least you know *why*.

Comment: It would be suitable indeed, but nobody except the derived class could call it anyway.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It doesn't really matter, since you're not allowed to construct objects of the base class anyway. Making it `protected` serves only as a reminder of the fact that the class is supposed to be a base class; it's only cosmetics/documentation.

Consider

```
struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
  protected:
    Base() { std::puts("Base constructor"); }
};

Base::~Base() { std::puts("Base destructor"); }

struct Derived : Base {};

int main()
{
    //Base b;   // compiler error
    Derived d;

    Base *b = new Derived();
    delete b;
}
```

Removing the `protected` doesn't change the meaning of the program in any way.

Comment: Why did you change the 'class' to 'struct'?

Comment: So he didn't have to write "public:" before the destructor I guess.

Answer (score 7):

#### Abstract classes and construction of such

It doesn't matter if the constructor is *public* or *protected*, since an *abstract class* cannot be instantiated.

You must inherit from it in order to have it's constructor called, and since the *Derived* class calls the constructor of the *abstract class* it doesn't matter what protection level you choose, as long as the *Derived* class can access it.

---

One reason that one could possibly have for making it `protected` is to serve as a reminder that the class must be constructed through inheritance, but honestly that should be clear enough when seeing that it has *pure virtual* member-functions.

---

#### example snippet

```
struct B {
  virtual void func () = 0;
  virtual ~B () = 0 { };
};

B::~B () { }
```

```
struct D : B {
  void func () override;
};
```

```
int main () {
  B b; // will error, no matter if Bs ctor is 'public' or 'protected'
       // due to pure virtual member-function

  D d; // legal, D has overriden `void B::func ()`
}
```

Comment: I agree that it should be clear, however for *clarity* purpose it may still help (though then it becomes subjective, of course).

Comment: About the "cannot be instantiated" part, the standard says: "no objects of an abstract class can be created except as subobjects of a class derived from it." More info at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42986059/2278206) answer to a related question.

Answer (score 3):

A pure virtual class cannot be instantiated, so it doesn't make a difference if the constructor is public or protected.

A public constructor *is syntactically correct*. However, making it protected will carry **a stronger indication** that the class cannot be instantiated.

For an example: http://ideone.com/L66Prq

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class PublicAbstract {
public:
    PublicAbstract() { }        
    virtual void doThings() =0;
};

class ProtectedAbstract {
protected:
    ProtectedAbstract() { }     
public:
    virtual void doMoreThings() =0;
};

class B: public PublicAbstract {
public:
    void doThings() { } 
};

class C: public ProtectedAbstract {
public:
    void doMoreThings() { } 
};

int main() {
    B b;
    C c;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A public constructor would not be very useful, since abstract classes cannot be instantiated in the first place.

A protected constructor makes sense: this way, a derived concrete class can provide its own public constructor that chains to the protected constructor of the base abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

**Protecetd ctor** will make sure the ctor gets called by only the classes which derive from `Abstract_base`.

**Public ctor** is not suitable because the class contains a `pure virtual` method! How are you planning to instantiate a pure-virtual class if not via its child classes?